# Как произвести копирование файлов по маске

Tags: java

Добрый день!
Ниже приведен код который копирует файл из одного места в другой, но копирует только указанный файл, например 1.xlsx
Вопрос:
Как модифицировать код, чтобы он копировал только файлы соответствующие маске
Например только файлы с расширением *.arj или только текстовый файлы *.txt или только те файлы которые начинаются скажем на 1

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileCopyExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        //Путь - откуда копируем
        String source = "C:/1/1.xlsx";
        //Путь - куда копируем
        String target ="C:/2/";

        //Имя исходного файла
        File sourceFile = new File(source);
        String name = sourceFile.getName();

        File targetFile = new File(target+name);
        System.out.println("Копируем файл : " + sourceFile.getName());

        //Копируем
        FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, targetFile);

        System.out.println("Файл скопирован");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

    public class GetAllFilesInDirectoryBasedOnExtensions {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            File target = new File("C:/2/");
            File dir = new File("dir");
            String[] extensions = new String[] { "txt", "jsp" };

            List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, extensions, true);
            for (File sourceFile : files) {
                System.out.println("file: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
                File targetFile = new File(target+sourceFile.getName());
                FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, target);
            }

        }

}
```

Поиск по имени файла:

```
File directory = new File("dor");
String baseName = "mysql-bin.";
FileUtils.listFiles(directory, new IOFileFilter() {

    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.getName().startsWith(baseName);
    }

    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return true;
    }
}, null);
```